# SQL: Extract Verified Users from the table using referral code

Tags: mysql

I have a query related to fetching total number of verified users.

I have a table named **table1**.

**Table:** table1

```
id    name      code    status    refer_from_code
1     Name1     R1      1         0
2     Name2     R2      0         R4
3     Name3     R3      1         R2
4     Name4     R4      0         R4
5     Name5     R5      0         R2
6     Name6     R6      1         R1
7     Name7     R7      1         R6
```

**Desired Results:**

```
id    name      total_referred     total_referred_verified
1     Name1     1                  1
2     Name2     2                  1
3     Name3     0                  0
4     Name4     2                  0
5     Name5     0                  0
6     Name6     1                  1
7     Name7     0                  0
```

**What I have done right now:**

I have written the below query for doing this task but its not working as it should be.

```
SELECT
    u.name,
    IFNULL(referrals.total_referred, 0) total_referrals
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        ui.refer_from_code,
        COUNT(*) AS total_referred
    FROM users ui
    GROUP BY ui.refer_from_code
) AS referrals ON referrals.refer_from_code = u.code
```

I want to do this using single MySQL query.

Comment: What is the version of your MySql?

Comment: Its 10.4.13-MariaDB

Comment: `SELECT id, name, (SELECT count(id) FROM table1 as T1 WHERE T1.code=T.refer_from_code) as total_referred FROM table1 as T`

Answer (score 0):

You can write it using `Common Table Expression` like this

```
with cte as (
select refer_from_code , 
count(*) as total_referred,
sum(status) as total_referred_verified
from users where refer_from_code!='0' group by refer_from_code
)

select 
t1.id,
t1.name,
coalesce(t2.total_referred,0) as total_referred,
coalesce(t2.total_referred_verified,0) as total_referred_verified
from 
users t1 left join cte t2 on t1.code=t2.refer_from_code
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=166bd2b90b06178004a049cff68d0770)